# Upload file to amazon s3 server using laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to amazon s3. Everything is clear with my codes I'm sure. Something wrong with amazon configurations.
This is my policy configuratin.

```
    {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

And I'm getting this error on my local server

> Error executing "PutObject" on "https://myBucketName.s3.eu-east-1.amazonaws.com/sort_asc.png"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: myBucketName.s3.eu-east-1.amazonaws.com (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

What's my error?

Comment: A "Could not resolve host" error has nothing to do with your IAM configuration. Where is this code running? On EC2 or somewhere else?
 What does your code look like? Are you not using the AWS SDK for PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an EU-east-1 region. Make sure you are using the right endpoint:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: I've chose US East (N. Virginia) for my bucket. it's eu-east-1, isn't it?

Comment: No, us-east-1 then, not eu-east-1

Comment: I've changed eu-east-1 to us-east-1 but seems nothing changes